# Error when Python calls Fortran with MPI: `[[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file ess_env_module.c`

Tags: python, fortran, mpi, f2py, mpi4py

I am trying to interface Python and Fortran.

I am stuck at the most trivial example (from here [mpi4py and f2py](https://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/tutorial.html)).

The example defines the following Fortran subroutine:

```
! file: helloworld.f90

 subroutine sayhello(comm)

 use mpi
 implicit none
 integer :: comm, rank, size, ierr
 call MPI_Comm_size(comm, size, ierr)
 call MPI_Comm_rank(comm, rank, ierr)
 print *, 'Hello, World! I am process ',rank,' of ',size,'.'
 end subroutine sayhello
```

The subroutine above is processed with f2py, through this command (Linux CLI):

```
$ f2py -c --fcompiler=gnu95 --f90exec=mpif90  --include-paths /usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/lib -lmpi helloworld.f90 -m helloworld
```

The command ends successfully, and the object helloworld.so is created.

I created the following python driver script (file `driver_helloworld.py`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#--------------
# Loaded Modules
#--------------
from mpi4py import MPI
import helloworld

#------------------------------------
# Set the MPI communicator
#-------------------------------------
fcomm = MPI.COMM_WORLD.py2f()

#-----------------------------------------
# Calling the Fortran subroutine
#-----------------------------------------
helloworld.sayhello(fcomm)
```

---

Running script above in serial works fine, namely:

```
$ python driver_helloworld.py
```

the output is the expected:

```
Hello, World! I am process            0  of            1 .
```

However, when I attempt to run through mpiexec, namely:

```
$ mpiexec -n 2 python driver_helloworld.py
```

I  obtain the following error:

```
[linux-box] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file ess_env_module.c at line 367

[linux-box] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file ess_env_module.c at line 367

[linux-box] tcp_peer_recv_connect_ack: invalid header type: 259457024

[linux-box] tcp_peer_recv_connect_ack: invalid header type: 259457024
```

I am using:

- Open MPI 1.10.2
- GNU Fortran (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
- Python 2.7.9

Does someone know what/where the problem is?

Comment: Please be careful about tags you are using. See the description of the [tag:python-2.7] tag. *"Do not use this tag if your purpose is to only convey the version of python you're using. Use the more generic [python] tag instead."* Also the generic [tag:mpi] tag is very important.

Comment: Are there multiple versions of OpenMPI on your computer? Double-check that `mpif90`  and `mpirun` uses the same version from the same location.

Comment: Also check `mpi4py` was built with the same MPI library than `mpirun`